# OpenGL VAO not working as intended

Tags: c++, opengl

From what I understand VAOs should store the states needed for rendering like the buffers and the attribute pointers.
But the problem I am having is, I need to set-up the VAO and load the data to the buffers every time before rendering or else the things being drawn is wrong.

I am using a class called mesh that hold the VAO and VBO handles as protected GLuint variables to initialize and load the vertex data into the GPU.

I searched for hours but it seams no one else is having the same problem.

So if I initialize like this and render  like this :

```
mesh coneMesh, sphereMesh, boxMesh;

coneMesh.setup(coneVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW, 1, ShaderA);
sphereMesh.setup(*sphereVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW,1, ShaderA);
boxMesh.setup(boxVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW, 1, ShaderA);
```

and in the rendering loop:

```
//sphereMesh.setup(*sphereVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW,1, ShaderA);
sphereMesh.render(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,sphereVertex->size(),0);
sphereMesh.render(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,sphereVertex->size(),1);

//coneMesh.setup(coneVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW, 1, ShaderA);
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
coneMesh.render(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,coneVertex.size(),2);
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

//boxMesh.setup(boxVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW, 1, ShaderA);
boxMesh.render(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, boxVertex.size());


glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

If I take out he comments and reinitialize the VAO and reload the data every thing works perfectly, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thank You

```
int mesh::setup(std::vector<vertex> &vert, GLenum BufferDataUsage, GLuint        nuberOfAttribute, shader &shad)
{

this->nuberOfAttribute = nuberOfAttribute;
this->shad = &shad;

std::vector<glm::vec3> position;
std::vector<glm::vec2> textureCoord;

position.reserve(vert.size());
textureCoord.reserve(vert.size());

for(unsigned int i; i<vert.size(); i++)
{
    position.push_back(vert[i].pos());
    textureCoord.push_back((vert[i].textureCoordinate));
}

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1,&vbo[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,(GLsizeiptr)vert.size() * sizeof (position[0]), &position[0], BufferDataUsage);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer ( ( GLuint ) 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,0,0);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

std::cout <<vbo[0]<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

And the rendering function:

```
void mesh::render(GLenum DrawHint,  GLint first,GLsizei count)
{
shad->bind();//glUseProgram(id)
//set up transform matrix and set up uniform

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(DrawHint, first, count);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

**Edit**

1.)I have ran the code in another machine and the problem didn't go away. So it's probably not a driver bug.

2.)I can confirm that the different VAO and VBO are not overwriting each other since the handles on each of them is unique.

3.) Now I have no idea what could possibly course this problem.

Comment: Have you tried a applying a heavy sprinkling of `glGetError`? See [this page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml). Also consider using the debug output if possible. [See here for some more info](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output)

Comment: I added this in the initialize stage and rendering loop :
        GLenum err;
        while ( ( err = glGetError() ) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << err;
        } and got nothing, thanks for the reply btw

Comment: There is a missing loop variable initialization in `for(unsigned int i; i<vert.size(); i++)`.

Comment: In the original there is another vector and VBO containing the texture coordinates, but I took them out for debugging. But having a unused vector should not be a problem though

Comment: At this point,  I am suspecting this is a driver bug. But I cant test it since I only have one computer on hand

Comment: Silly question: can `vao` change between 'setup' and 'render' ?

Comment: Maybe if you make an [mcve], could be easier to help

Comment: @Ripi2 No, the vao handle is a protected class variable that only changes when setup is called

Answer (score 0):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Unbinding the VBO has to go **after** unbinding the VAO, as otherwise VAO will remember your VBO not being bound.

**EDIT**

As pointed out in comments, it's OK to unbind `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` before unbinding the VAO. It wouldn't be OK for `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, which is not used in this example though.

Therefore, the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Nonsense. Binding to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` does not affect the VAO's state. Only calling `glVertexAttribPointer` will affect the VAO's state.

Comment: @NicolBolas My bad. What I said applies to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER not to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.