# VBO limits and GPU memory overflow

Tags: c++, opengl

This is a fllowup question on [OpenGL VAO not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136260/opengl-vao-not-working-as-intended) which is still unsolved.

I am suspecting my GPU is runing out of memory and caucusing VBO being deleted automatically. Causing some for some of the VAO to not being drain properly.

So I am here to ask if this is likely the case and how opengl deals with VBO and GPU memory overflows.

Thkanks

Comment: In my knowledge, the GPU sets "GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY" only when a call for buffer (a texture is also a buffer) memory reserve fails. No crash. No deletions. This way you have a chance to delete other buffers (or even shaders) and make room for new data.

Comment: So the error occurs on the glGenBuffers line on run time?

Comment: No, after [`glBufferData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml).  No idea what'll happen if you get anywhere near 2^32 VBO names from `glGenBuffers()`.